# Can you manage your Playstation Plus account from another console?

Tags: playstation-plus

I've had a PS4 Playstation Plus account for years, love it, it's great.
I have a cousin with cerebral palsy which live out of state who also loves gaming.

Is there a way I can share my account with him, or create an account for him that I can manage from my console?

Thanks for any help in advance.